# Defining app bar in App.xaml in Win 8 Metro app

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my app, the app bar, its buttons and its event handlers are consistent across the several pages of my app. Is it possible to define and initialize the app bar in the App.xaml.* files, so that it gets defined once, as opposed to in each page of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can host the App bar in a single page, and then have that page host and manage the navigation of your other pages.  Microsoft's example of this is pretty straightforward.

[Share App bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150604.aspx)